# WooCommerce - Get product variation SKU in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the product variation SKU's but it always returns blank. I've tried everything I can think of so far and I have been unable to find any answer here.

```php
          foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {
            $variation_id = $variation->ID;
            $variant = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
            
            // Get data from the product variation
            $excerpt_var = wpautop($variation['variation_description']);
            $sku = $variation['sku'];
            $price = $variation['display_regular_price'];
            $price = number_format($price, 0, ',', ' ');
            if ($price != null) {
              $price = $price . ",-";
            }

            $results[] = array(
              "id" => $available_variations,
              "cat" => $cat->name,
              "sku" => $sku,
              "title" => $title,
              "price" => $price != null ? $price : "",
              "excerpt" => $excerpt_var,
              "thumbnail" => $thumbnail,
              "type" => "variation"
            );
          }
```

Whole function to get all prods and variations is here:

```php
function get_all_prods_for_csv() {
  $results = array(); // Rows to be returned

  // Settings
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $title = '';
  $empty = 0;
  // Query arguments
    $args_cat = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'show_count' => 0, // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    'pad_counts' => 0, // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    'hierarchical' => 0, // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $empty
    );
  // For all categories
    foreach (get_categories( $args_cat ) as $cat) {

    // If root category
        if ($cat->category_parent === 0) {

            $category_id = $cat->term_id;
            $category_slug = $cat->slug;
            $cat_thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
      $cat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $cat_thumbnail_id ); 
      
      $results[] = array(
        "id" => $category_id,
        "cat" => $cat->name,
        "sku" => '',
        "title" => '',
        "price" => '',
        "excerpt" => category_description( $category_id ),
        "thumbnail" => $thumbnail,
        "type" => "category"
      );

      // Get all products for current category
      // Query arguments
            $args_prod = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'order' => 'asc',
        'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category_id
          )
        )
            );
      $products = get_posts( $args_prod );
      
      // For all products
      foreach ( $products as $prod ) {

        $product = wc_get_product($prod->ID);
        // Get data from the product
        $title = $product->get_title();
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($prod->ID);
        $excerpt = wpautop($product->get_short_description()); // wpautop(get_the_excerpt($prod->ID));
        
        // If single variation
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
          $price = $product->get_price();
          $price = number_format($price, 0, ',', ' ');
          $results[] = array(
            "id" => $prod->ID,
            "cat" => $cat->name,
            "sku" => $product->get_sku(),
            "title" => $title,
            "price" => $price != null ? $price . "" : "",
            "excerpt" => $excerpt,
            "thumbnail" => $thumbnail,
            "type" => "simple"
          );
        } else if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
          $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
          $counting_variations = 1;
          foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {
            $counting_variations++;
          }

          $results[] = array(
            "id" => $prod->ID,
            "cat" => $cat->name,
            "sku" => "",
            "title" => $title,
            "price" => "",
            "excerpt" => $excerpt,
            "thumbnail" => $thumbnail,
            "type" => "variation_root"
          );


          foreach ($available_variations as $variation) {
            $variation_id = $variation->ID;
            $variant = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
            
            // Get data from the product variation
            $excerpt_var = wpautop($variation['variation_description']);
            $sku = $variation['sku'];
            $price = $variation['display_regular_price'];
            $price = number_format($price, 0, ',', ' ');
            if ($price != null) {
              $price = $price . ",-";
            }

            $results[] = array(
              "id" => $available_variations,
              "cat" => $cat->name,
              "sku" => $sku,
              "title" => $title,
              "price" => $price != null ? $price : "",
              "excerpt" => $excerpt_var,
              "thumbnail" => $thumbnail,
              "type" => "variation"
            );
          } 
        }
      }
        }           
  }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Looks like the program never enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$sku = $variation['sku'];
```

should be

```
$sku = $variant['sku'];
```

since you get the object as that variable `$variant`.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work :( I made sure that the products had an SKU but they still return blank fields